# Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I would like to check if my JavaScript exist. I tried almost all possible solution but faild. please help me to let me know where i am mistaken.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (ScriptManager2.IsInAsyncPostBack)
            {
                ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
                if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("AddRoleJScript"))
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>");
                    sb.Append("Sys.Application.add_load(func);");
                    sb.Append("function func() {");
                    sb.Append("jScript();");
                    sb.Append("func_addRows();");
                    sb.Append("}");
                    sb.Append("</script>");
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "AddRoleJScript", sb.ToString(), false);
                }
            }
     }
```

I am using upadate panel so every time when update panel click the script will be register.

Comment: dont write javascript code, call javascript method instead of inline code and then try

Comment: have you written  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager> in your aspx page?

Comment: @viveknuna yes i already write the script working fine but when i post back the script working two time on single click becuse script registered on every post back

Comment: or change last parameter from false to true, If you want to include script tag and then try

Comment: if i changed false to true script not working. I don't know much about script tag

Comment: put in if(!PostBack) block

Comment: for some scripting resons i cant do that. i only can find registered script key from Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("key") which we provide at the time for registrarstartupScript.

Comment: i find this way on msdn but i dont know why Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered is not working

Comment: Page.ClientScript. does not work with UpdatePanel? Do We have similar property in ScriptManager?

Comment: thanks i dont know about that so is there any other way you can suggest me.

Comment: Yes, You can use ViewState to store one count and check if its 1 or not, or you can use Session or Cookies

Comment: You can use hidden field or a invisible control in which you can set value and get it

Comment: try Page.IsStartupScriptRegistered instead of Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered

Comment: good idea. but do u think its a good way to do that?

Comment: Page.IsStartupScriptRegistered is obsolete according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isstartupscriptregistered(v=vs.110).aspx